# onclick show and hide data in react.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

i have component which is showing data in the webpage 
 I want to write another component and create buutton in it. which just hide other component on clicking the button and show basic input field form.

My code is something like this

component app

```
    class  App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
      this.state= {
        filter: null,
        };
       this.setFilter = this.setFilter.bind(this);

     }

    setFilter(filter) {
       this.setState({filter: filter})
    }


     render(){


       let filteredPassword = details_data.filter(
        (detail) =>{
            console.log(detail.website.toLowerCase(), this.state.filter)
            return detail.website.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.filter)!= -1;
        }
       );

       return (

        <ul>
            <Filter onUpdateFilter={this.setFilter} />
            {
                filteredPassword.map((detail)=>{
                    return <Detail item={detail}
                    key={detail.id}/>
                })
            }

        </ul>

     )
   }
}
```

Another Detail component 
      class Filter extends React.Component{

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
        search: 'Search'
      }
  }

   updateSearch(event) {
    this.props.onUpdateFilter(event.target.value.substr(0,40))
  }

   formShow(){

   }

  render() {

    return (
        <div>

            <input id="search" type="text" placeholder={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}/>
            &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
            <input id="button1" type="button" value="+" onClick={this.formShow()}/>


        </div>
       )
   }
 }
```

Few other component like this.

i am trying to hide the table and form button above is used to "show form" button.

```
  class Form extends React.Component {



    render() {

      return(
        <div>
        <form>

            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="username" />

        </form>
          </div>
      )


   }
 }
```

Guide me how to do this.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking too much to your code (it's a bit messy) it seems to me what you want to achieve is to communicate two components. Component A will react to a button click event and tell: 1) component B to hide and 2) component C to show up.

The way of doing this depends on if the components have hierarchical relationship or not. I would recommend start by reading this [chapter](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) of the official React documentation. Then, [here](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/) is also a great article on component communication strategies in React.

On top of that, some patterns that focus specifically on this have achieved great success, like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Hope it helps.